# Load Button when Function is Finished

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I have a issue with adding a button that should become visible after a Java script function is completed.

Code source:

```
"https://codepen.io/arcs/pen/rYXrNQ"
```

Note: code is not mine obviously and I take no any credit for this

Elaboration:

I moved this code to a simple html page, everything went fine.
Once the registry form is finished, text message will display with a small time delay.

What I would like to have here is, a button with timeout function (a bit longer than text message) under the text message, from where I can navigate the user to the next page.

Once again, when the entire process of this code is finished, text message will load.
I need a button to load below that text.

I need button to move user to the next page, so it should contain a link and open in same tab could be also added.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to go to the first page again ? A button that appears under the final message, and takes you to the first page again ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. No, I need button to move user to the next page, so it should contain a link and open in same tab could be also added.

Comment: right after `setTimeout(function() { h1.style.opacity = 1; ...` add another setTimeout() to load the button

Comment: Hi @ZohirSalak I was able to spot that, but I would appreciate if you could give me the entire line of an example, because I already added many variations and everything result as a failure.

Comment: It's rather simple just another **setTimeout()** `setTimeout(function(){ the code that adds the button with the functionality },[ your delay ])`

Comment: Should I make a button with ID and add it to HTML too? (sounds like no) If I got it right, I should just create a button function from here, and everything is done? I hope so, thanks for helping.

Comment: here i made some changes to get you started it's all commented , had to fork the pen it didn't let me save a new one https://codepen.io/Zohir/pen/PoqJzoe?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

First off create an 'a' tag with the link to the next page. Make sure you give it an id for the javascript part.

```
<a id="button" href="path_to/nextpage.html">Text for the button</a>
```

Do add basic CSS to it like position, width, and height. Set the opacity to 0 and pointer-events to none.

```
//other properties
opacity:0;
pointer-events:none;
//other properties
```

Once you have done this, just get a variable to point to the  tag and add another setTimeout function which sets the opacity to 1 and pointer-events to all

```
var nextbtn = document.getElementById("button"); //or whatever id you gave the <a> tag
setTimeout(function() {
    nextbtn.style.opacity = "1";
    nextbtn.style.pointerEvents="auto"
  }, 500);// you can change the delay to suit your requirements
```

I hope this clears your issue. Have a good day!

Comment: Why use `opacity` when you have `visibility`?

Comment: that works too. I use opacity as I find it easier to manipulate. In another project of mine which invovled showing a div as a transition since i cannot transition between different gradients. I tried `visibility` instead of `opacity` and it wasn't wokring. Could have very well been my code. But yeah, both work just fine.